# Using Axlsx gem to create a bar chart that references another sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, charts, axlsx

I'm currently using the Axlsx gem to create bar charts in excel. However, I'm trying to create a bar chart on one sheet that references values on another sheet but am running into errors.

Here's my code:

```
sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart, :start_at => "B5", :end_at => "I25", :title=> "Top Weight Step (0.5-15) Volume Month over Month", :barDir => :col) do |bars|
   bars.add_series :data => sheet["'Weightsteps Month over Month'!F10:F25"],
    :labels => sheet["'Weightsteps Month over Month'!B10:B25"], 
    :title => sheet["'Weightsteps Month over Month'!F9"]
   bars.valAxis.gridlines = false
   bars.catAxis.gridlines = false
end
```

Comment: what's your error message?

Comment: The error message I get is
   `NoMethodError: undefined method 'row' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't been able to find a solution. In the meantime a workaround would just to be to call the data you need onto the current sheet and create the chart using those values. So instead I did:

```
15.times do |count|
   sheet.add_row ["='Weightsteps Month over Month'!B#{count}",
                  "='Weightsteps Month over Month'!C#{count}"]
end

sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart, 
   :start_at => "D5", 
   :end_at => "I20", 
   :title=> "Top Weight Step (0.5-15) Volume Month over Month", 
   :barDir => :col) do |bars|

   bars.add_series 
   :data => sheet["A1:A15"], 
   :labels => sheet["B1:B15"]
end
```